# Symbolic link all files in directory to show in another directory?

Tags: ftp, symbolic-link

What I want is to be able to display all files that are ftp'd into /home/ftp in /srv/ftp

/srv/ftp is password protected, and has files in it which I don't want to be accessible from the public ftp.

So as such I wish that all files uploaded to /home/ftp are automatically symbolically linked (or otherwise) to /srv/ftp. Does this make sense?

e.g. `ls /srv/ftp`:

```
file.sh
another.txt
something_else.i386
```

then a user ftp's and drops a file in /home/ftp (or ssh, or whatever)

`ls /home/ftp`:

```
user_file.mk
```

`ls /srv/ftp`:

```
file.sh
another.txt
something_else.i386
user_file.mk
```

I hope this makes sense. I have been told that this can probably be achieved using `ln` to create symbolic links, but I don't want to have to ssh in and create the links every time I (or someone else) puts files over ftp.

Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you are looking at a script of some kind, and, IMO I would run rsync from cron. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line at the end of your crontab would achieve what you want:

```
*/1 * * * * ln -s /home/ftp/* /srv/ftp
```

To edit your crontab:

```
crontab -e
```

With this, */home/ftp/* will be scanned every minute and the appropriate symlinks made in */srv/ftp/*.

*Crontab is the command-line equivalent of Scheduled Tasks.
For details about its syntax, check out [this page](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/#more-534).*

Comment: Glad to help :)